# Client side alert Bert for Meteor 1.10.2 failed install due to no fourseven:scss binaries

Tags: javascript, meteor

I had this meteor code working good on older meteor version, now the code is being moved to a meteor 1.10.2. on a windows 10 machine. The error below happens when trying to install [Bert](https://github.com/themeteorchef/bert).

Any suggestions on an easy fix?
Thanks

```js
>meteor add themeteorchef:bert
 => Errors while adding packages:

While loading package fourseven:scss@4.10.0:
error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c
C:\Users\fred\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd
rebuild --update-binary
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

sass for meteor is [saying](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-scss):

Since meteor 1.4.1+ (fourseven:scss 3.9.0+), we do not have prebuild binaries anymore. You are required to set up the required toolchain yourselves.